# css align text of an absolute td

Tags: css

I have a table with style `margin: 0 auto;` to put it in the center of outer div. With this trick, if the width of table changed, the content of the table will be moved in order to remain the table in the center of the div, which is what I don't want to happen.

```
<p:row>
    <p:column>
        <p:outputLabel for="moduleTitle" value="Module Title: " />
    </p:column>
    <p:column colspan="2" style="vertical-align: central; position: absolute;">
        <p:outputLabel id="moduleTitle" value="#{classroomBean.classroom.module.moduleTitle}"/>
    </p:column>
</p:row>
```

The 1st row, 2nd column of the table has dynamic value, so I set `position: absolute;` to this column to avoid it changes the width of the table. But after I set its position to absolute, the align function doesn't work anymore.
[image]

As you can see from the print screen above, it align top of the `td` instead of the default `center`, anyone has idea on how to align content of an absolute positioned `td`?

Comment: `vertical-align:center` is an error.

Comment: then what is the solution? @MrLister

Comment: `vertical-align:middle`. But the way I understand the problem (correct me if I'm wrong, preferably by showing more code) is that the solution is to not use absolute positioning, but to set `table-layout` to `fixed` and give each each column a width explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add a fixed width to the table and then let it overflow?

Anyway, it's not really good typography what you're doing, but if this is what you want then create a class for your colspan="2" row.

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(0, -50%);
```

It moves the element 50% down and then up again for the half width of the element's height.

More reading about centering things:
https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: this doesn't work, it moves the element to the center of the screen instead of the `td`. BTW, how to fix the table width and let it overflow?

Comment: You need to add `position: relative` to your p:row so your absolute element doesn't escape it.

For table width, just add "max-width: 500px" or anything to your p:row. overflow will happen autmatically. And do this with css classes instead of using the style property.